# Can I get the Instagram access_token multiple times using the same code?

Tags: instagram, access-token

I'm currently using my own Instagram account (not that of my users) to get an access_token, and thus I don't need to create an explicit server-side authentication flow for myself to get the code. I can then use the code programmatically to get an access_token without any human interaction.

My question is, for the purposes of an app that only requires the owner's code to get an access_token, does Instagram let you reuse the same code so that you don't have to keep manually entering a new one?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using a single account, there is **currently** no need to request new access tokens repeatedly.  You should be authenticating one time, and storing that access token to use with calls to the API endpoints.

Instagram access tokens currently have no set expiration, however may expire at any time in the future.  So you may reuse the token indefinitely (for now), but build the system to be prepared to request a new token in the event that the stored token expires.

Per http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/:

> Note that we do not include an expiry time. Our access_tokens have no
>   explicit expiry, though your app should handle the case that either
>   the user revokes access or we expire the token after some period of
>   time. In this case, your response’s meta will contain an
>   “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenError”. In other words: do do not assume
>   your access_token is valid forever.